# Is there any software related with effective field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

I'm working on standard model effective field theory(SMEFT), I want to improve my calculation about loop correction from higher dimensional operators. But I don't whether those loop corrections can also be done using computer, I mean some softwares like **Feynarts** or **Feyncalc** for renormalizable theories, can someone give me some tips? Thanks a lot.